# How to send javascript variable and form data on same time in django?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

i have javascript variable and i want to sent it to django view with ajax() method here is my code.

```
$('#orderDetails').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'order/',
                headers: {"X-CSRFToken":'{{ csrf_token }}'},
                data: {
                    'test': 12,
                 }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

here is form code

```
<form action="{% url 'order:order_detail' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="orderDetails">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit"  value="Proceed" class="btn">
</form>
```

and here is **views.py**

```
def order_detail(request):
    test = request.POST.get('test')
    print(test)
```

it print none.any one can help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your view currently handles only GET requests and is not aware of POST request. You should set the view like below.

```
def order_detail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = request.POST.get('test')
        print(test)
```

Comment: I would also try to set dataType to json inside of ajax. And check if you are posting to the right url.